# Twitter Authentication failure

Tags: android, twitter

I am implementing twitter in my app.I am facing a problem in tweeting. In DDMS it says:

Authorization failure exception 401: This can happen only if consumer key was not correct or signatures did not match.

I have registered my app many times and rechecked code. Can anyone tell me where may be i am going wrong in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown what you're doing. So no one can tell where you went wrong.

Comment: don't worry i got it , i was not using any callback URL

Comment: You can answer your own question. That way when someone else has the same problem, they can find your answer.